# Installing GD Library for php 5.6

Tags: php, gd

I'm working on a CentOS machine (version 6.7).. I installed php 5.6 in this machine (previously was 5.3) and actually I want to install the GD library of PHP using this command line :

```
sudo yum install php56u-gd
```

And it gives me this error messages

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.gtcomm.net
 * elrepo: ftp.osuosl.org
 * epel: ftp.osuosl.org
 * extras: centos.mirror.gtcomm.net
 * ius: ius.mirror.constant.com
 * remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: centos.mirror.iweb.ca
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56u-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.ius.centos6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-common(x86-64) = 5.6.23-1.ius.centos6 for package: php56u-gd-5.6.23-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56u-common.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.ius.centos6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-pecl-jsonc(x86-64) for package: php56u-common-5.6.23-1.ius.centos6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56u-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.9-2.ius.centos6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-pear for package: php56u-pecl-jsonc-1.3.9-2.ius.centos6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-pear for package: php56u-pecl-jsonc-1.3.9-2.ius.centos6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56u-pear.noarch 1:1.10.1-4.ius.centos6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-xml for package: 1:php56u-pear-1.10.1-4.ius.centos6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-posix for package: 1:php56u-pear-1.10.1-4.ius.centos6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-cli for package: 1:php56u-pear-1.10.1-4.ius.centos6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56u-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.ius.centos6 will be installed
---> Package php56u-process.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.ius.centos6 will be installed
---> Package php56u-xml.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.ius.centos6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
```

How may I resolve this issue? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolved my problem ... Here is the steps that I followed:

- Remove php and its modules:
  On CentOS I used :

`yum remove php php-cli php-common php-gd php-ldap php-mysql php-odbc php-pdo php-pear php-pecl-apc php-pecl-memcache php-pgsql php-soap php-xml php-xmlrpc`

- Re-Install the needed PHP modules (that I need in my case): 
  `sudo yum install php56w`
  `sudo yum install php56w-mysql`
- Finally Install the GD Library :  `sudo yum install php56w-gd`

And all working good actually